# rigging separate objects to one skeleton

Tags: modeling, rigging, rigify

So recently ive decided to try to make a full model from sculpting,texturing and rigging it, though im a little stumped. i dont know much about rigging and was curious about how you rig separate object to the same rig. all the parts in green are separate and im not sure if theres a good way to use the same rig to for all of it withougt having to merge it all and keep the spikes from bending and looking floppy. also i cant seem to get rigify to to recognize the bottom jaw, i have control over the whole head but cant close the mouth and was wondering if theres a special thing you have to do for that [image]

Comment: You can keep separate objects and parent them all to one unique armature, but in your case I'm not it has an interest. And you can always correct the weights in Weight Paint mode, so even if the Automatic Weight doesn't work fine with the jaw you'll be able to correct that.

Comment: ah i see i see, thank you